# Boolean Control flow variable is not correctly implementing

Tags: python, boolean, conditional-statements

I have the following code, but it doesn't control the flow to allow player2 to roll the dice, when playing=false. Can anyone spot the error? Basically, it never gets to: RollTwoDiceP2 and I can't figure out why.

Note: I have tried to set playing (the boolean variable) to false, in RollTwoDiceP1, in the hope that on going back to the playerturns() function, this time around it would go to RollTwoDiceP2 (Player2 turn sub). That doesn't work

```
    def callmatrix(player1,player2, n):
    print("*************LOADING GAME******************")
    print("Welcome:", player1,"and", player2)
    for i in matrix(n):
            print(i)
    playing = True
    playerturns(player1,player2,playing)

def playerturns(player1,player2,playing):
    print(" - - - - - - - - - - ")
    print("Press Enter to contnue")
    #playing = True
    while(playing):     
        roll=input()
        if roll=="r" or "R":
            RollTwoDiceP1(player1,player2)
        else:
            RollTwoDiceP2(player1,player2)


def RollTwoDiceP1(player1,player2):
    turn=input("Player 1, it's your turn to roll the dice: Press r to roll:>>>")
    #create two variables here and assign them random numbers
    die1=random.randint(1,6)
    die2=random.randint(1,6)

    #add the two die numbers together
    roll=die1+die2

    #when you are printing an integer, you need to cast it into a string before you printit
    print("Player1: You rolled a:", die1, "and a", die2, "which give you a:", roll)

    playing = False
    playerturns(player1,player2,playing)

def RollTwoDiceP2(player1,player2):
    turn=input("Player 2, it's your turn to roll the dice: Press r to roll:>>>")
    #create two variables here and assign them random numbers
    die1=random.randint(1,6)
    die2=random.randint(1,6)

    #add the two die numbers together
    roll=die1+die2    


    print("Player2: You rolled a:", die1, "and a", die2, "which give you a:", roll)

    playing = True
    playerturns(player1,player2,7,playing)
```

The output:

```
Continually asks Player 1 to Roll. Prints the result of Player 1s roll (repeat)
```

This is a logic error, so it is NOT a duplicate of the problem specified.

Comment: @TidB - no, I am not asking how to do something, but rather for the logic in my program to be analysed and a suggestion given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the line `if roll=="r" or "R":`. First, we evaluate `roll=="r"`, which might be true or false, and then `"R"`, which is *always* true. Since it's combined with an `or`, the statement is always true and the `else` branch isn't executed. Change the statement to `if roll == "r" or roll == "R":` or better `if roll.lower() == "r":`

Comment: Thank you - that needed a fix. However, on correcting that, the same error occurs. still going to Player 1 repeatedly

Comment: What are you typing to go to player 2?

Comment: ah, found the error, and also thanks to your fix. I needed to BREAK to exit the loop as it was still inside the IF statement (I'm referring to the loop in the playerturns()

Comment: I think your logic is flawed, or at least it appears to be. You print "press enter to continue", so you're probably hitting enter, right? But that means you're entering *nothing* in the `roll=input()` line, which is then used in the comparison. I think you want a separate `input()` to catch just the enter key. The `turn` variable where you prompt to enter `r` is not even used. So you might want to take a step back and look at your program's structure.

Comment: As mentioned above, it was fixed with your suggestion and then the break to exit the loop! Thanks very much @TidB